# Where to find the images for old Ubuntu Beta Releases?

Tags: iso, beta

As a developer and a power user, I'd like to know from where can I download the images for old Betas like, Saucy Beta, Quantal Beta, and some EOL Beta releases.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not all Beta releases are available, I've found this one though:

http://old-releases.ubuntu.com/releases/10.10/

11.10 beta2 iso can be found here:

http://kambing.ui.ac.id/iso/ubuntu/cdimage/releases/11.10/beta-2/

Comment: Is a 11.10 Beta available?

Comment: I added a link to 11.10 beta2 iso, HTH